# Using interpolation outside function definition in solution using Runge-Kutta 4th order

Tags: matlab, interpolation, anonymous-function, runge-kutta

I have written MATLAB code to solve the following systems of differential equations.

[image]
with [image] 
where [image] 
and    *z<sub>2</sub>* = *x<sub>2</sub>* + (1+*a*)*x<sub>1</sub>*

```
a = 2;
k = 1+a;  
b = 3;
ca = 5;
cb = 2; 

theta1t = 0:.1:10;
theta1 = ca*normpdf(theta1t-5);

theta2t = 0:.1:10;
theta2 = cb*ones(1,101);

h = 0.05;
t = 1:h:10;

y = zeros(2,length(t));  

y(1,1) = 1;  % <-- The initial value of y  at time 1
y(2,1) = 0;  % <-- The initial value of y' at time 1

f = @(t,y) [y(2)+interp1(theta1t,theta1,t,'spline')*y(1)*sin(y(2));
            interp1(theta2t,theta2,t,'spline')*(y(2)^2)+y(1)-y(1)-y(1)-(1+a)*y(2)-k*(y(2)+(1+a)*y(1))];

for i=1:(length(t)-1)  % At each step in the loop below, changed y(i) to y(:,i) to accommodate multi results
   k1 = f( t(i)      , y(:,i)         );
   k2 = f( t(i)+0.5*h, y(:,i)+0.5*h*k1);
   k3 = f( t(i)+0.5*h, y(:,i)+0.5*h*k2);
   k4 = f( t(i)+    h, y(:,i)+    h*k3);
   y(:,i+1) = y(:,i) + (1/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)*h; 
end 

plot(t,y(:,:),'r','LineWidth',2);
legend('RK4');
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('y')
```

Now what is want to do is define the interpolations/extrapolations outside the function definition like

```
theta1_interp = interp1(theta1t,theta1,t,'spline');
theta2_interp = interp1(theta2t,theta2,t,'spline');
f = @(t,y) [y(2)+theta1_interp*y(1)*sin(y(2));
           theta2_interp*(y(2)^2)+y(1)-y(1)-y(1)-(1+a)*y(2)-k*(y(2)+(1+a)*y(1))];
```

But this gives the error
[image]

Please suggest a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in your original code:

```
f = @(t,y) [y(2)+interp1(theta1t,theta1,t,'spline')*y(1)*sin(y(2));
            interp1(theta2t,theta2,t,'spline')*(y(2)^2)+y(1)-y(1)-y(1)-(1+a)*y(2)-k*(y(2)+(1+a)*y(1))];
```

the call to `interp1` uses the input variable `t`. `t` inside this anonymous function is not the same as the `t` outside of it, where it is defined as a vector.

This means that, when you do

```
theta1_interp = interp1(theta1t,theta1,t,'spline');
```

then `theta1_interp` is a vector containing interpolated values for all your `t`s, not just one. One way around this is to create more anonymous functions:

```
theta1_interp = @(t) interp1(theta1t,theta1,t,'spline');
theta2_interp = @(t) interp1(theta2t,theta2,t,'spline');
f = @(t,y) [y(2)+theta1_interp(t)*y(1)*sin(y(2));
            theta2_interp(t)*(y(2)^2)+y(1)-y(1)-y(1)-(1+a)*y(2)-k*(y(2)+(1+a)*y(1))];
```

Though this doesn't really improve your code in any way over the original.